# Translating Mathematical (Universal/Existential Quantifier) Statements into English?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Can anyone confirm if I have these correct? Or if not, where I am going wrong?

> Translate these statements into English, where $K(x)$ is '$x$ is a Kangaroo' and $H(x)$ is '$x$ hops' and the domain consists of all animals.

- (a) - $\forall x(K(x)\rightarrow H(x))$ - "All animals that hop are Kangaroos."
- (b) - $\forall x(K(x) \land H(x))$ - "All animals are Kangaroos and hop."
- (c) - $\exists x(K(x) \rightarrow H(x))$ - "There exists a Kangaroo that hops."
- (d) - $\exists x(K(x) \land H(x))$ - "There exists an animal that is a Kangaroo and Hops."

Comment: (a) should be the other way around ("For all animals, if it is a kangaroo then it hops"). (b) I agree. (c) "There exists an animal such that if it is a kangaroo then it hops". (d) I agree.

Comment: Notice that your English translations of (c) and (d) are equivalent statements in English: if you find an animal that is a kangaroo and hops, then you have found a kangaroo that hops, and vice versa. But the statements on the math side are not equivalent.

Comment: Is the goal to try to preserve the structure of the mathematical sentences as much as possible, or to write an equivalent statement in (relatively) easy-to-understand English?

Comment: @DavidK, as I understand the instructions, it is to preserve the structure of the mathematical sentences (as much as possible) in the English language.

Comment: Then a literal translation of (a) then perhaps should be "Every animal, if it is a kangaroo, hops." Or in better English with the same logical connectives: "Every animal hops if it is a kangaroo."

Answer (score 1):

If you can come up with good "test cases",
you can use them to help you decide if your translations are correct.

Consider statement (a):

$$\forall x(K(x)\rightarrow H(x)).$$

This statement is satisfied in a universe in which the only animals are
some kangaroos (every one of which hops), 
some frogs (every one of which also hops), and some snakes (which never hop).
Let $x$ be any animal in this universe.
Then either $x$ is a snake, so $K(x)\rightarrow H(x)$ is true because
the antecedent is false;
or $x$ is a frog, so $K(x)\rightarrow H(x)$ is true because
the conclusion is true (also because the antecedent is false);
or $x$ is a kangaroo, so $K(x)\rightarrow H(x)$ is true because
the conclusion is true.

But it is not true in this universe that all animals that hop are kangaroos.
Indeed, there are some frogs in this universe which are animals that hop
but are not kangaroos.

An alternative way to translate $\forall x.P(x)$, where the domain of $x$
is "animals", is to start with the words
"Every animal" and continue with an English phrase meaning 
"satisfies $P(x)$ where $x$ is that animal."
The expression $K(x)\rightarrow H(x)$ signifies
that if $x$ is a kangaroo, $x$ hops;
so we might translate (a) as,
"Every animal is such that if it is a kangaroo, it hops."

The preceding quoted sentence is very awkward English, however.
An alternative wording is,
"Every animal, if it is a kangaroo, hops."
But most people, I think, would have more trouble parsing this
sentence than it is really worth.
Another alternative is to recognize that a common English translation of
$K(x)\rightarrow H(x)$ is, "$x$ hops if $x$ is a kangaroo."
Therefore the fully quantified statement in (a) could be translated,
"Every animal hops if it is a kangaroo."

We can check that the universe of kangaroos, frogs, and snakes satisfies
all of the actual sentences above that start with "Every animal."

On the other hand, if we introduce a kangaroo into our universe
that cannot hop because it has no legs, the mathematical statement (a)
is falsified and so are all of the "Every animal" translations of it.
This of course does not *prove* that the translation is accurate,
but it is a good test case to weed out inaccurate translations.

I would use similar techniques of modeling and translation for the
other sentences, keeping in mind that sometimes a statement that starts
with $\exists x$ can be translated into English starting with the
words, "Some animal."
Also keep in mind that good models for existential quantifiers
are often minimalistic, for example, a universe with only a single frog and no other animals satisfies (c); so does a universe populated only by a single snake.
But a universe whose entire animal population consists of legless kangaroos
does not satisfy (c).